# Local printer redirection problems in Terminal Services

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, windows-terminal-services, printer

I have several WinXP clients that are connecting to a Win2003 Terminal Server. I've had trouble getting them to map their local printer into the Terminal session.I have tried so many things but only one client can map its printer to terminal session. I have done this things at this article => http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/08/24/terminal-server-and-printer-redirection.aspx

Comment: Printer redirection under 2003 really doesn't work well.  There are 3rd party clients that make it better by doing some translation client side.  Are you willing to spend some cash?   Windows 2008 has Easy Print which also works much better.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the event error indicated in that article?
Type: Error 
Event ID: 1111 
Description: Driver drivername required for printer printertype is unknown. Contact the administrator to install the driver before you log in again.

That is the usual cause i have seen for this. The driver has to be exactly the same for it to be picked up.

What i have done in the past is to create the printers as local printers on the terminal server and secure them with security groups. This has the benefit of not having to rely on the printer mapping each time. If you are going beyond one or two servers though then the admin overhead starts to cause problems.